# How do I schedule a notification in Android 13?

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, android-permissions, android-pendingintent

Previous questions on Stack Overflow do not account for Android 13's new permission model, hence I am opening a new question.

My app currently uses an AlarmManager to set a notification for a user at a pre-defined point in the future. Think of this as a 'reminder' before an event happens, at a period defined by the user (e.g 0/1/5/15/30 minutes before the event)

In Android 13, there are 2 new permissions I now need to think about:

- `SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM` – To schedule a PendingIntent to wake up the device to deliver a notification. The reminder/notification is a secondary feature in my app, which I why I do *not* use the other permission (`USE_EXACT_ALARM`)
- `POST_NOTIFICATIONS` – To actually show the notification to the user.

Does this mean that for new users to my app, I will now need to send them through two separate permission acceptance flows?

Specifically, for `POST_NOTIFICATIONS` a runtime dialog to accept or deny notifications AND for `SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM` an Intent to the user's Settings app to allow alarms & reminders (so that I can schedule notifications in the future).

Two separate permission flows feels sub-optimal. Am I reading this correctly, or is there a more user-friendly way to schedule notifications in the future?

Relevant documentation is here:

- [Notification Permission](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission)
- [Alarm Permission](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms#using-schedule-exact-permission)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this scenario, I ended up building a permission acceptance flow in my app.

In short, my app checks whether both `SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM` and `POST_NOTIFICATIONS` have been granted by the user. If one of them hasn't been granted, the user is not able to schedule notifications and I automatically send the user through a permission setup experience.

In Android 13, this isn't too bad because `SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM` is automatically granted to the user (although they can of course disable this, so the app still needs to check for this permission), so the user just has the `POST_NOTIFICATIONS` permission to grant.

I expect in Android 14+ that the `SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM` will not be automatically granted. This is frustrating for this scenario, because unlike `POST_NOTIFICATIONS` which has a nice runtime dialog, `SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM` involves deep linking the user out of my app into Android Settings. This app switch is a suboptimal experience.

I have attached some images of how I approach this in my app. If there is a better way to achieve this, I would be open to ideas, but this has solved this issue for the moment.

| **1: Permission Setup Screen** | **2: Grant Permission: POST_NOTIFICATIONS** |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Permission Setup Screen] | [image: POST_NOTIFICATIONS Grant] |
| **3: Grant Permission: SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM** | **4: All Permissions Ready** |
| [image: SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM Grant] | [image: All Permissions Ready] |